# Filtering children by parents with XPath

Tags: html, xml, xpath, scrapy

I have HTML similar to this:

```
<div>
    <h4><a href="#">Don't Match Me</a></h4>
    <a href="#">Match Me</a>
    <a href="#">Match Me</a>
    <a href="#">Match Me</a>
</div>
```

How would I select all of the `a` elements not inside of a `h4`? I tried `a[not(ancestor::h4)]`, but I honestly have no idea what I'm doing.

Also, as a small side question, is there a Scrapy selector class that implements PyQuery or BeautifulSoup?

Comment: `a[not(ancestor::h4)]` should work - what exactly is the problem?  Is it selecting all the `a` elements including the one you don't want or is it failing to select anything at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the Scrapy selector you should use:

```
hxs.select('//a[not(ancestor::h4)]/text()').extract()
```